# Which one is more idiomatic: "Count backwards from 100 in twos." or "Count backwards from 100 by twos."

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, idiomatic-language

> Count backwards from 100 **in** twos.
>
> Count backwards from 100 **by** twos.

I have seen both "in twos" or "by twos" are used in the same sense. I wonder which one is more idiomatic?

Comment: This [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=count+backwards+by+*%2Ccount+backwards+in+*&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) indicates no preference for one over the other.

Comment: This may be a regional difference.  To me, from the Northeastern US, "count **by**" sounds much more natural.

Comment: I wish I could put this in one graph, but it's too long for a single Ngrams query.  Basically, it looks like [**in** is British usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=count+backwards+in+threes%3Aeng_gb_2019%2Ccount+backwards+by+threes%3Aeng_gb_2019&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3), and [**by** is American usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=count+backwards+in+threes%3Aeng_us_2019%2Ccount+backwards+by+threes%3Aeng_us_2019&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be regional differences, but both expressions are reasonable (for a fairly rare instruction out of a numeracy class)